# grep: Not a recognized flag: R

Tags: grep, aix

if AIX has no -r flag for grep command, how to do recursive search in a folder?
I don't know the version of AIX but I think it is 4.3

```
grep -R IBM /tmp
grep: Not a recognized flag: R
Usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwy] [-p[parasep]] -e pattern_list...
    [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
```

Comment: use -r or --recursive or -d recurse,  do a man grep to find the proper one

Comment: Doesn't look like a programming question in this form. Ask on [Unix.se]

Answer (score 1):

given you have 'xargs' and 'find' installed:

```
find /tmp -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep IBM
```

a try.

-print0 is essential when reaching files/folder containing weird white-spaces.

Comment: find /tmp -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep IBM   
    find: 0652-017 -print0 is not a valid option.   
    xargs: The -0 flag is not valid.

Comment: for a quick fix you should try it without the 0 options: `find /tmp -type f | xargs grep IBM `